# Como faço para integrar meu projeto Django com o Scrapy?

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django, web-crawler, scrapy

Estou querendo desenvolver um projeto simples usando **Django** onde criarei uma página web e essa página irá capturar dados de outras páginas. O problema é que não consigo integrar o **Scrapy** com **Django**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe possibilidade de usar os 'pipeline' do Scrapy para integrar diretamente com os models do Django ([link](http://marcela-campo.blogspot.com.br/2015/03/scraping-website-using-scrapy-and-django.html)).

Também é possível executar o teu spider como uma script que te retorna um 'json' ([link](https://tryolabs.com/blog/2011/09/27/calling-scrapy-python-script/)). No exemplo do link provavelmente algumas funções estarão 'deprecated', mas a doc é suficiente para começar.